# Plugin for Marathon Running Event Management

Tags: plugin-recommendation, events

Is there a plugin that works to be a marathon running event management tool? I need things like ways to accept registrations, payments, and displaying the results when the event is over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it difficult for you to find a plugin **SPECIFIC** for marathon, but you can check out some "normal" event managers like :

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-events-registration/

or

http://wp-events-plugin.com/events-manager-pro/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/events-manager/